# NHLambdaExtensions: Create a Criterion object to add to ICriteria later

Tags: criteria, icriteria, nhlambdaextensions

My application creates a dynamically generated query at runtime based on user input by creating Criterion objects e.g:

```
ICriterion criterion = Restrictions.Eq("Name", "John");
......
detachedCriteriaSomewhereElse.Add(criterion);
```

How do I do this in NHLambdaExtensions?

what I really need to do is

```
ICriterion criterion = Restrictions.Eq<Person>(p=>  p.Name == "John");
```

but this isn't valid.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the NHLambdaExtensions you have the SQLExpression class that lets you do the following:

```
ICriterion criterion = SqlExpression.CriterionFor<Person>(p => p.Name == "John");
```